# WPF TabControl ContentTemplate List

Tags: wpf, list, tabcontrol, contenttemplate

Inexperienced with WPF, so I need a little help. Appreciate the help in advance.

I have the following class:

```
public class TabDefn
{
    public TabDefn() { }

    public TabDefn(string inFolderName, List<FilesFolder> inFilesFolders)
    {
        folderName = inFolderName;
        FFs = inFilesFolders;
    }

    public string folderName { get; set; }
    public List<FilesFolder> FFs {get; set;}
}

public class FilesFolder
     {
    public FilesFolder() {}

    //public Image image { get; set; }
    public string ffName { get; set; }
    //public Image arrow { get; set; }
}
```

The `TabControl.ItemContent` is working fine. I can't get anything to show up for the `TabControl.ContentTemplate`. I've tried many things, but this is where the WPF is right now:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden" Name="Actions">
   <!-- This displays the tab heading perfectly.-->
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding folderName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <!-- This is the content of the tab that I can't get anything to show up in.-->
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FF}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <TextBox Text="{Binding ffName}"  />
                  </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         </ListBox>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I don't care if the content changes, so I don't need the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ObservableCollection`. However, if I have to put all that code in, so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `FF` as field which is invalid binding source. You need to convert it into property

```
public List<FilesFolders> FF { get; set; }
```

and initialize it for example in `TabDefn` constructor. You can find more as to what is a valid binding source on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Stupid mistake. Sometime looking at something so long, miss obvious. I edited the class above, but still nothing in TabControl.ContentTemplate. I can see the data I'm sending to the ItemsSource.

Comment: NVM. Found last problem. I'm getting something, even though it's not right. Probably a simple fix. Thanks so much.